# Typescript can not infer constructor return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```
type ArrayBufferViewConstructor<T> = new (buffer: ArrayBufferLike, byteOffset?: number, byteLength?: number) => T;

function asView<V, C extends ArrayBufferViewConstructor<V>>(
    TypedArray: C,
    v: BufferSource,
    byteOffset?: number,
    byteLength?: number,
  ): V{
    return undefined as V
  }

let a = asView(Uint8Array, new Uint32Array)
a
```

**D.TS**

```
declare type ArrayBufferViewConstructor<T> = new (buffer: ArrayBufferLike, byteOffset?: number, byteLength?: number) => T;
declare function asView<V, C extends ArrayBufferViewConstructor<V>>(TypedArray: C, v: BufferSource, byteOffset?: number, byteLength?: number): V;
declare let a: unknown;
```

I expected `a` is `Uint8Array`, but got `unknown`

**Compiler Options**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "target": "ES2017",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

**Playground Link:** [Provided](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAggJwQQzAIQK4DMtQQNQEsoB3AYQHsA7AZxAQwGMQKEAeAFQD4YBeGKqRgAKAEbZcCAFzwkqTDjwAZQgGsoAGhiiwIKAHkcNKCAD8MqhgC2ovFp16lUKgHMQAC3MDrthAEo+Hg4AbmBgLAwqZkJqGGQaIlI2fC0yGCgADz0qABMaWRR0CTxE8mo6BmZWZK4uYWAYRpgOSCgcxEKZMg0GpoA3GQVJAGUKDARGTV7GhwMjEy9LGztp7V0oJ1cPRZ8Vxr8ZfABvVYQTcaoYSJyoLEJBHLj8-F6AXzCAGxM4vifS4QAqvcQAAODqoLSCEgwIFUEAAZgATOCwH5gMggA)

How do define the type make return type is `Uint8Array` ?

Comment: Typed arrays have multiple overloads for their constructors.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WGA6oN) work for you? Ignore my previous comment; turns out that had no effect on the result.

Comment: @caTS  works, except has to cast every result to instance type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making use of the built-in [`InstanceType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype), there is no need for the generic parameter `V`. We just need to use it here, in the return type of the function:

```
): InstanceType<C> {
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wgQ6ym)